# Facebook Page Tab: Change App-Back-Link of Wall Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I have created a Page Tab App for Facebook. This App makes a Wall Post entry in the name of the FB-User via PHP . The Posts have a Link "by", to show that it's a post of my App. But the URL of this "Back-Link" is not correct. It goes to https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxx and does not work. Where can i change this URL?!

Picture to explain the "Back-Link" http://kunden.316tn.com/download/howchangeurl.jpg

Comment: You can’t – from the app settings alone, FB does not know what page your app might be embedded on (it might even be multiple pages after all). If you are just using your app on one single page – then you could set up a canvas app as well (this is where FB links to), and have that redirect to your page tab app via JS.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot to @CBroe. To define a canvas app too solved my Problem! Thank you.